# Jinja2 / Nunjucks: Different treatment to for-loop elements

Tags: jinja2, nunjucks, templating-engine

I have a list:

```
list = [a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, a, b, c, 1, 2, 3]
```

And I want to show it as a table, where every 4th, 5th & 6th element is styled in its own way, e.g like this.:

```
<td><span class="label label-info">1</span></td>
<td><span class="label label-danger">2</span></td>
<td><span class="label label-primary">3</span></td>
```

I am batching the list into 6er rows to display it as a table like this:

```
{%- for row in list|batch(6, '&nbsp;') %}
    <tr>
    {%- for column in row %}
        <td>{{ column }}</td>
    {%- endfor %}
    </tr>
{%- endfor %}
```

But I have no idea how to do what I described above. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loop.index`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) to tell which number an iteration is at in a loop:

```
{%- for row in list|batch(6, '&nbsp;') %}
    <tr>
    {%- for column in row %}
        <td>
            {%- if loop.index == 4 %}<span class="label label-info">{% endif -%}
            {%- if loop.index == 5 %}<span class="label label-danger">{% endif -%}
            {%- if loop.index == 6 %}<span class="label label-primary">{% endif -%}
            {{ column }}
            {%- if loop.index in [4, 5, 6] %}</span>{% endif -%}
        </td>
    {%- endfor %}
    </tr>
{%- endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a `span`-wrapper, the code can be written as

```
{% set classes = {4: 'label label-info', 5: 'label label-danger', 6: 'label label-primary'} %}
{%- for row in list | batch(6, '&nbsp;') %}
    <tr>
    {% for column in row %}
        <td class = "{{classes[loop.index]}}">{{column}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

P.S. Imho, `{%-` and `-%}` clog a code up. The better way is use html beautifier on end of page generation. If you use `Express`, see a [express-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-beautify) middleware.